# SSD Mobilenet v1 coco - Should I resize images before I label them for training?

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

I am using a Dell server with 2 Nvidia V100 GPUs, Ubuntu 16.04, Tensorflow 1.7.

I am trying to figure out about when to resize my images.  In the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config, it has

image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 300
    width: 300
  }
}

I have drawn bounding boxes on many, many images with a total of 10 classes.  The images are different sizes, some large, some small.  My detection of objects is performing very poorly.  I tried resizing a bunch of the images down to 300x300 then redrawing the bounding boxes, but this does not help and the images are pretty low quality and scaled incorrectly.

My question is:  Do I need to scale my images to 300x300 before I label them?  If I don't do that, will SSD Mobilenet do the resize and my bounding boxes will not line up or are they resized appropriately along with the images?  I don't want to draw bounding boxes on large images then have them not be correct when SSD Mobilenet does the resize.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i can't really answer to your question since i don't know how are you learning your SSD MobileNet.

I assume that you want to use your own dataset and convert it into tfrecord, right?

- If so, you will have to handle the resizing on your own
- If you are going to use COCO dataset, you can use pycocotools in order to create desired tfrecord

Best regards,
Vaclav